# Get values stdClass Object PHP

Tags: php, object

I work with mp4 data extract php script. this returns a  stdClass Object as below. can anyone tell me how to show the duration from below object. 
thank you

```
stdClass Object
(
    [hasVideo] => 1
    [hasAudio] => 1
    [video] => stdClass Object
        (
            [width] => 472
            [height] => 360
            [codec] => 224
            [codecStr] => H.264
        )

    [audio] => stdClass Object
        (
            [codec] => 224
            [codecStr] => AAC
        )

    [duration] => 622.8
)
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You could do:

```
echo $yourObject->duration;
```

Comment: How to if the stdClass Object has numbers in keys insted of string?
@Blaster

Comment: @ram Open a Question?

Comment: For an object with hyphens or numbers you could do `$yourObject->{'duration-123'}`