# Display the value from a returned object

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have a variable object which stores the value below.

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [term_id] => 1
            [name] => Uncategorized
            [slug] => uncategorized
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 1
            [taxonomy] => category
            [description] => 
            [parent] => 0
            [count] => 4
            [object_id] => 39
            [cat_ID] => 1
            [category_count] => 4
            [category_description] => 
            [cat_name] => Uncategorized
            [category_nicename] => uncategorized
            [category_parent] => 0
        )

)
```

I now want to display the `slug` from the list of values. How do i do so?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get values stdClass Object PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231638/get-values-stdclass-object-php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that object is stored in an array called `$array`:

```
echo $array[0]->slug
```

Comment: If this isn't working please post more code because it's correct for the given  information.

Answer (score 1):

You can use print_r($yourObject) to print out the entire object for debugging or if you want to print just that value this would work: echo($yourObject[0]->slug); .

If there are multiple array indices then this:

```
foreach($yourObject as $object)
{
    echo $object->slug;
}
```

Comment: Updated try again, if that is not working perhaps more of your code needs to be show. This is the correct method.

Answer (score 1):

Jonh gave you an exact answer...let me explain it a bit

```
$obj = your_array;//from where you are using var_dump() to see these values..
```

and then

```
echo $obj->slug
```

you can use the same technique for other terms in your dump, like

`echo $obj->name`

HTH