# How to get object(stdClass) value in php?

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have some object like this :

```
object(stdClass)#188 (1) { ["0"]=> string(1) "1" }
```

How could I print that object value in php ?

Thank you.

Comment: use var_dump()...

Comment: If you type that exact question into google. You get multiple answers.Here is the [first one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231638/get-values-stdclass-object-php) and it answers your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, Best way for single value

```
echo $objects->{"0"};
```

and for multiple values

```
foreach($objects as $val )
{
    echo $val;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Very short answer

```
var_dump($obj->{'0'});
```

Comment: @RuchishParikh But this is answer

Answer (score 0):

You have access to the internal content of  the Object via: `->{"0"}`.  Assuming you want to use the variable or echo it out for some reasons, you can simply do:

```
 <?php echo $object->{"0"}; ?>
```