# How to get array stdClass Object value

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have a similar question to [Get values stdClass Object PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231638/get-values-stdclass-object-php?r=SearchResults&s=1|188.0345) however, I'm kinda lost in the answer of what was the object is he referring to.

Here's the code, and wanting to get the value of `avg_open_rate` and `avg_click_rate` from `$statsInfo[]` and display it to my output text copy.

```
if ( wp_remote_retrieve_response_code( $response ) == 200 ) {
  foreach ( $body->members as $member ) {
    if( $member->unique_email_id != '4b6354db09' )
      continue;
    $user = $member->email_address;
    $statsInfo[] = $member->stats;
  }
  print_r( $statsInfo );

  echo '<p> User: '. $user .' </p>';
  echo '<p> Click Rate: '. $statsInfo->avg_click_rate .' </p>';
  echo '<p> Open Rate: '. $statsInfo->avg_open_rate .' </p>';
} else {
  echo '<b>' . wp_remote_retrieve_response_code( $response ) . wp_remote_retrieve_response_message( $response ) . ':</b> ' . $body->detail;
}
```

Ouput on print_r and echo:

```
Array ( 
  [0] => stdClass Object ( 
    [avg_open_rate] => 0 
    [avg_click_rate] => 0 
  )
)

User: john@doe.com
Click Rate:
Open Rate:
```

Comment: Your `$statsInfo` is an array of stdObject, so you have to use array index to access  the stdObject first:  `$statsInfo[0]->avg_open_rate`, `$statsInfo[0]->avg_click_rate`

Comment: ok, i figured out what was I missed there.. thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Do you understand what @catcon is telling you?

Comment: Why don't you just print the stats inside the `foreach` loop?

Comment: You're overwriting `$user` each time through the loop. At the end it will be the last user, not all the users whose stats you collected.

Comment: @waterloomatt yeah, and already figured it out...